# Should Stack Overflow tag [jq] continue to alias to [jquery]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

A command line tool I've been using a while now is called jq. I'd like to ask some questions / help people with the kung-fu that is sometimes required. They may not even be suited to Stack Overflow very well (perhaps more suited for Super User) but it is effectively Bash scripting so it's not totally off the mark.

However, whenever you tag something [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq), it gets auto tagged [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), resulting in a lot of strange JavaScript answers usually something along the lines of "*that's so easy, you don't even need jQuery*" ... which is a bit annoying.

jq project homepage: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Why is jq synonymized with jquery in the first place?

Comment: Aw, crap.  There are a ridiculous number of synonyms for jQuery.  jq, jquery-chaining, jquery-color, jquery-toggle, jquery-events, jquery-event-binding, jquery-ajax, jquery-each, jquery-functions, and jquery-object

Comment: @Robert Harvey: There are. And from the looks of it, all of them (with the obvious exception of jq) seem warranted.

Comment: For what it's worth, the ZK client engine's [reimplementation of jQuery](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/jsdoc/_global_/jq.html) is named `jq`, so it's possible that tag will be used in that sense in the future.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there a way to quickly find tags and their synonyms? I mean, without having to open each tag's page. It might be good to have such a tree view to make it easy to suggest tags for pruning.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently there are folks out there who abbreviate jQuery as jQ for whatever reason, even though I've never seen any official references to said abbreviation.

I removed the synonym. It was never a synonym in the first place.